# Setting up RMySQL for Shiny Server

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, shiny-server

I'm running shiny server from ubuntu 14.04 x64, it seems to work fine.

I am having issues with setting up RMySQL package though. I have installed it from command line and it recognizes it.

I also installed it from RStudio on my system and it recognizes it, I can connect to the host and such, but when I try to run connection in server.R I get an error:

```
Error in library(RMySQL) : there is no package called ‘RMySQL’
```

Here is my server.R (very basic):

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password', dbname='dbname', host='localhost')
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from test")
data = fetch(rs, n=-1)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'black')
  })
})
```

Any ideas? Or anything else you would like me to add?

Comment: It seems that you don't have RMySQL installed. Maybe when you tried, the installation didn't end well and you didn't realize it. You need libmysqlclient-dev system package to install RMySQL, just in case that is the problem.

Comment: @nicola I have the libmysqlclient-dev installed and here are the last lines of command line install:

Comment: ** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘format’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘RMySQL’
Creating a generic function for ‘print’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘RMySQL’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RMySQL)

Comment: Very strange. What happens if you just open R and try `library(RMySQL)`? Did you install RMySQL through install.packages()? Do you have more than one R installation on your pc?

Comment: Command line works. Also R-studio works. Let me check the multiple R installations.

Comment: So when I login as shiny user I cannot find the RMySQL, which means there is either another R install or it doesn't have the path for the installation.

Comment: Here are the libPaths() on shiny user: [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"

Comment: Here they are on my user: [1] "/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"              
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                     "/usr/lib/R/library"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the shiny user did not have a path to packages installed from my system user. I corrected it by loggin as shiny and exporting the path. Thank you nicola for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

With Shiny , I use to install packages with command sudo R and than

install.packages('RMySQL) .

It didn't seem to work for RMySQL ,

I had to login as shiny user and install RMySQL.

Since i didn't knew password of shiny user , i had to do sudo passwd shiny 
and change the password.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The issue was a path for the shiny user not containing the the packages. I just had to add them.